# Filtering analytic details table in Power BI Sankey chart causing incorrect summary amounts, how can I recalculate accurately?

Tags: powerbi, dax, summarize, sankey-diagram

I have two tables imported from the same source, where the principal has a summary of the amounts (used in the Sankey chart) and a secondary (related) table that has the analytic details, I'm trying to filter (using visualization) from analytic details and visualize the change in Sankey chart at a summary level. I want to have a column at this table when the analyst hit the filter from analytic detail the summary recalculates considering this selection. Currently, I have the filter for nodes and links corrected selected, however, the amount does not correspond to the selection.

I want to see the correct amount per summary considering the selection made by the interface from the user.